# How to add a transition to logo shrink

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've found a code online which shrinks the header, I've added code to idd to make the logo shrink on scroll.

Now I want to add a transition so the logo resizes with the same effect the header does. I can't seem to get it working.

Javascript

```js
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
    <script>
       
    // logo laten krimpen 
    window.onscroll = function() {
      growShrinkLogo()
    };
    function growShrinkLogo() {
      var Logo = document.getElementById("Logo")
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 5 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 5) {
        Logo.style.width = '80px';
      } else {
        Logo.style.width = '150px';
      }
    }
    // resize header 
    jQuery(function($){
      $(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(document).scrollTop() > 30) {
            $('#section-padding').addClass('reduce-section-padding');
            $('#row-width').addClass('increase-row-width');
        } else {
           $('#section-padding').removeClass('reduce-section-padding');
           $('#section-padding').addClass('slow-transition');
           $('#row-width').removeClass('increase-row-width');
           $('#row-width').addClass('slow-transition');
         
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
    <?php } );
```

And here is the css:

```css
.reduce-section-padding {
transition: all 0.9s ease-out 0s;
padding-top: 0px !important;
padding-bottom: 0px !important;
margin-top: 0px !important;
}
 
.increase-row-width {
transition: all 0.9s ease-out 0s;
width: 100% !important;
}
 
.slow-transition {
transition: all 0.9s ease-out 0s;
}
 
#main-content {
margin-top: 0vw;
}
```

I've added the javascript made css class slow-transition to the logo but didn't seem to work.

Hope someone notices something about the code that I didn't.

Comment: Did you check and see if your script is output to the HTML?

Comment: i'm sorry how do you mean that? 

The CSS classes are being added and are working. The only problem is the transition for the logo shrinking, the header is working just fine!